# When are the fibres numerically equivalent?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be an algebraic fibre space, and $\dim Y=1$.  What can I say about the numerical relation of the fibres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are algebraically equivalent, which is stronger. Consider the subvariety on $X \times Y$ which is the inverse image of the diagonal on $Y \times Y$ under $(f,id)$. This is flat, because it's a hypersurface in a flat morphism, so all its fibers, which are the fibers of $f$, are algebraically equivalent.

This is only true as long as none of the fibers contain entire irreducible components $X$, which seems to be allowed in the definition of algebraic fiber bundle that I saw, but is obviously a pretty pathological scenario.